# What is the running time of the algorithm? is it O(sqrt(n)) or O(log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, scala, performance, runtime, big-o

**EDIT: Constraints value Range [2,1000000000] and a<=b**

```
 def sqrtoccurrence(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
        val sqrtA = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(a)).toInt
        val sqrtB = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(b)).toInt
        if(sqrtA > sqrtB) 0
        else 1 + sqrtoccurrence(sqrtA, sqrtB)      
      }
```

is it O(sqrt(n)) or O(log(n))? I'm not good at calculating recursive running times. I know its the depth of the tree and how many times the recursive function is called. and how much the constant work sqrt affects in this case so whether it can be ignored or not? But maybe I'm wrong. An explanation with help greatly. 
Thanks

Comment: What does *n* represent here? I see no *n* in your code or your algorithm.

Comment: This code seems to be flawed. It will never finish if you set a <= 1 and b >= 1. If a > 1 then it seems to be O(sqrt(n)) although if a and b are random numbers it will terminate immediately about half of the times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would reason about the necessary running time.  In the best case when `a > b`, no recursion is required hence it's an `O(1)` operation.  When `a <= b` the only thing at play to make `ceil(sqrt(a)) > floor(sqrt(b))` possible is for the repetitive `sqrt()` of `a` and `b` to reduce their difference to be less than the rounding error.

In a worst-case scenario, we're looking at how the repetitive `sqrt()` of a large `b` "shrinks" to meet the termination requirement with a small `a`.  Hence I would characterize the running time of the function on input `n` as:

```
T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + C  // where C is O(1)
```

To compute an approximate number of necessary recursions, `r`, we could look at the final value of the repetitive `sqrt()` of `n` at the end of the recursions, say `m`, and establish an equation with the following logic:

> `m` is the result of applying `sqrt()` to `n` for `r` times

Hence,

```
(..(m^2)^2)^2 ... )^2 = n  // `r` times of `^2`
```

i.e.

```
m^(2^r) = n
```

This implies:

```
2^r = log(n)     // log base `m`

r = log(log(n))  // outer log base `2`
```

Thus, the time complexity is `O(log(log(n)))`.

---

```
sqrtoccurrence(2, 10)           // 1
sqrtoccurrence(2, 100)          // 2
sqrtoccurrence(2, 1000)         // 3
sqrtoccurrence(2, 1000000)      // 4
sqrtoccurrence(2, Int.MaxValue) // 4

def log2(x: Double): Double = math.log(x) / math.log(2)

log2(log2(10))           // 1.732
log2(log2(100))          // 2.732
log2(log2(1000))         // 3.317
log2(log2(1000000))      // 4.317
log2(log2(Int.MaxValue)) // 4.954
```

Comment: let `a=b=2^17` . Then `sqrt(a)=sqrt(b) = 362.03` ; this means `f(a,b) = 0` and is calculated in only one iteration, but `log(log(n)) = 4.09`. It gets worse as n gets larger. Maybe `log log n` is the complexity for when a and b are of the form *2^k*.

Comment: @jrook, there is always best-case scenario (in this case `a >= b`) that the running time is far less than what the big-O suggests.  Keep in mind, though, `log(log(n))` would barely grow beyond 4.9 even if you make `n` significantly bigger than `2^17`.  In fact, `log(log(Int.MaxValue)) < 5.0`.  And that's in line with the result in my brief testing of `sqrtoccurrence` with small `a` and large `b`, which is a non-best case the time complexity approximation is based on.

Comment: Hi leo, I think this is the correct answer but could you explain the answer pls. how did you deduced Olog(log(n)).
Specially 
"I'm going to assert that the rate of the value gain of ceil(sqrt(a)) over floor(sqrt(b)) will be predominantly dictated by the "shrinking" rate of sqrt()"

Comment: @jrook big-O means the worst case, not best case. f(a,b) =0 is the best case its not O notation.

Comment: @gamer, I've expanded the answer to hopefully make the explanation clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From the other answer we have

```
T(n) = T(sqrt(n)) + C
```

Now let

```
2^m = n
```

Rewriting

```
T(2^m) = T(sqrt(2^m)) + C
       = T(2^(m/2)) + C
```

Let us define a new function

```
S(m) = T(2^m)
```

Then

```
S(m) = T(2^m)
     = T(2^(m/2)) + C
     = S(m/2) + 2C
```

We know now that

```
S(m) = O(log m)
```

Therefore

```
T(n) = T(2^m) = S(m) = O(log m) = O(log log n)
```